# how to apply filters on my input signal

Tags: matlab, filtering, matlab-guide

my program has a function which is getting the cutoff frequency from the user and save it to (fc). then apply a high pass filter on a sine wave.

i tried to use the function (fdesign.highpass) and use my fc as a vairable to the fp but its not helping.

also i tried to do it by using RC transfer function, the output doesn`t act well with fc.

if someone could help me and give me an example about how to use variables inside fdesign.highpass function, or any other way can do the same job.

I am really thankful for your helping, I am new to matlab, so the documentation was a little bit hard to follow.

- notes: I know the frequency for my input signal, also the magnitude.

Comment: What other constraints do you have on the filter characteristics (Type of Filter (Butterworth, Bessel, ...) or type of design strategy, damping in stopband, etc.)? Also, what is your sample rate? And then note that applying a highpass filter to a sine wave will not really have an effect.
If the cutoff is higher than the frequency of the sine wave, nothing will happen, otherwise the amplitude will be lower, but there will be no alteration of the waveform (except for phase shift).

Comment: this is the first time dealing with filters, all what i understand that if my fc was 10 Hz for example, that means any signal under 10 Hz won`t pass. and if my fc was bigger than my input frequency that means all my input signal won`t pass.

Comment: Well, that is a simplified view on the filter action. Whether you can use it depends heavily on the thing you want to acchieve. It is good for estimating the spectral contents of a signal, it is very bad for the calculation of an actual response (obviously!). The question here is: what do you want to do? *Why* do you want to apply a filter to a sine wave? If you know exactly your input signal than you don't kneed a filter.

Comment: i want to use it for educational process. to show an example how the high pass filter will effect the sine wave,so i have two graphs, one for the original signal (the sine wave), the other is for the high pass filtered sine wave in a specific cutoff frequency in the limit of the frequency of the original wave.

Comment: Ok, so as i understand it, you don't really care about filter order and type of reponse (not filter type, but whether you use a bessel filter, or butterworth or else). If that is the case, just use a one pole filter and directly calculate the amplitude and phase shift yourself. Use that to generate a new sine wave and you have your result. If this is in your interest, i can formulate an anwser to this question to show this.